# How to consult dependency graph for gradle plugin

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle, dependency-management, gradle-plugin

I'm having trouble with a transitive dependency from a custom grade plugin of mine. However, I'm not finding a way to generate the dependency tree on the project where I apply the plugin.

This is my build.gradle.kts file:

```
plugins{
    id("myPlugin") version "1.0.0"
}
```

And when I generate the dependency tree for the whole project I get this as output:

```
❯ ./gradlew dependencies

> Task :dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project 'myProject'
------------------------------------------------------------

No configurations

A web-based, searchable dependency report is available by adding the --scan option.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 933ms
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Is there a way to generate the graph for the plugin itself? Or to generate the whole buildscript dependency graph?

Comment: Did you try with maven?

Comment: I don't think you can run a gradle plugin in maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this help:

```
./gradlew buildEnvironment
```

ref https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

Comment: Yes, this in fact shows the dependency tree for the plugins thanks!